# Facebook share button for website

Tags: php

i need to use share button in my website. Different share button for different products.. mostly we need to use like this,

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
```

In the above url what are all the parameters we need to pass for showing it as our website, product and some image of that product in that share page...

Comment: Well there's no way you could find that out yourself using google.

Comment: Check the FB API reference for that, it depends by what method (FB SDK or frame) you choose to use. But AFAIK, the sharer button has been abandoned in favor of the LIKE/RECCOMAND button, so you should turn towards using this instead.

Answer (score 0):

You asked what parameters you need to pass it to have it show up as your site, etc.  The like button uses its own Graph Protocol API to do this, it essentially makes your page a facebook page and can be read as such.  It's written like XML and defines things such as the thumbnail you want to show as your picture, the shortname of the site, etc.  Go to developers.facebook.com to read all about the facebook API and app development and integrating into your webpage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you cand use [this on github](https://github.com/amirsa00/share-content) to share content on social media (includes facebook) and make your custom button!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Facebook Like also. It performs the same as the Facebook share now appearing in your Facebook newsfeed with thumbnail, or

You can use some plugins like add this or you can use the following link:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```